# Oracle 11g Top N Query returns different values to the same query running under 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11gr2

I have created a simplistic example of this problem.
The following query returns nulls for all columns that are not present in the order by clause.  If I run the query against 10g then it is fine.  This is a basic implementation of a top n query.

I know the inner select statement is ineficient but the SQL is generated (I can change the engine though if necessary).

All help is greatly appreciated!

```
select  * from (
    select b.* from USER_table b 
    where b.id in (
      select c.id from USER_table c where c.removed = 0
    ) 
     order by surname
) a where rownum <= 10



--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table USER_TABLE
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "CHRONICLE"."USER_TABLE" 
   (    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SURNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "REMOVED" NUMBER, 
    "ID" NUMBER
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE     DEFAULT     CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index USER_TABLE_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CHRONICLE"."USER_TABLE_PK" ON "CHRONICLE"."USER_TABLE" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT     CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table USER_TABLE
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "CHRONICLE"."USER_TABLE" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "CHRONICLE"."USER_TABLE" ADD CONSTRAINT "USER_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT  CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE;
```

The oracle version is 10.2.0.1.

It is running on Windows 2008 R2 x64

Explain Plan for 11g

[image: Explain Plan For 11g]

Explain Plan for 10g

[image: Explain Plan For 10g]

Comment: Can you post the full 4 digit version of the 11g database that you are using and the query plan that is generated?  If 11g is returning NULL where the data is not NULL, that's a bug.  Have you (or your DBA) applied all the patches to the 11g database?

Comment: The first question I would ask is the order of the data the same between 10g and 11g if you take the rownum portion of the query away?  Also note there were MAJOR changes in the Optimization Engine between 10g and 11g2.  The other option to "test" with is to change the Cost Based Optimizer to be at the 10.2.0.1 comp level and test again.

Comment: The full version number is 11.2.0.1.  Are the version of oracle to download fully patched or should I be looking somewhere else for patches.  The database is running on Windows 2008 R2 x64.

Comment: The order of the data is exactly the same in both versions.  I have only placed 3 rows in each table.  How do I change the cost based optimizer?

Comment: I have added explain plans for both 10 and 11g

Answer (score 2):

I applied ORACLE 11G 11.2.0.1 PATCH 13 BUG FOR WINDOWS (64-BIT AMD64 AND INTEL EM64 (Patch)), and this has resolved the issue.  I also attempted to look in the bug database to locate the specific reason but this is easier said than done!

Thanks for your suggestions